# Django: How to filter a queryset by a another model in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a model `Course` and another model `Video` that is a ForeignKey to the `Course` model. Now what I want to do is this, I want to display all the videos related to a course and display the videos `count` along side the name of the course in a list view not in the detail view.

This is the code I've written but it keep showing an error:

`The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.`

views.py

```py
def my_courses(request):
    courses = Course.objects.filter(course_creator=request.user)
    lectures = Video.objects.filter(course=courses).count()
    
    context = {
        'courses': courses,
        'lectures':lectures,
    }
    return render(request, 'dashboard/my_course.html', context)
```

models.py

```py
class Course(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    course_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    course_creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete.models.CASCADE)



class Video(models.Model):
    title  = models.CharField(max_length = 100 , null = False)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course , null = False , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video_id = models.CharField(max_length = 100 , null = False)
    is_preview = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

my-courses.html

```
{% for course in courses %}
   <a>{{ course.course_title }}</a>
   <a>{{ course.price}}</a>
   <td>{{course.video.all.count}} Videos</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you share your models.py?

Comment: @LaCharcaSoftware i have shared the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your views:

```
def my_courses(request):
    courses = Course.objects.filter(course_creator=request.user)
    context = {
        'courses': courses,
    }
    return render(request, 'dashboard/my_course.html', context)
```

On your templates:

```
{% for c in courses %}
    {% for v in c.video_set.all %}
         {{v.title}} 
    {% endfor  %}
{% endfor %}
```

With this code, for example, you iterate through all the videos of the courses and get the video title.

EDIT:
You can make your models more "user friendly" adding a "related_name" to the video model. So you can access to the videos just doing this:

```
videos_of_a_course = course.videos.all()
```

In models.py:

```
class Video(models.Model):
...
course = models.ForeignKey(Course , null = False , on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="videos")
....
```

Comment: Yes, it is also can be the way of doing it, but the OP doesn't shared the template and what does `course_creator`  indicates in the `Course` model?

Comment: @SunderamDubey  i have updated the question, there is `course_creator` field in the course model like this `course_creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete.models.CASCADE)`